# Where do I place this coffee script in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My controller is in app/controllers/admin/customer_service/tickets_controller.rb

I've written a tickets.js.coffee script for use in the show view...

Just wondering where do I put it, to be automatically included?

app/assets/javascript/admin/customer_services/tickets.js.coffee ?

Everything I've tried isn't working...

Answer (score 1):

In your `application.js` file, there are directives about which files are to be included. Make sure your file is included, and that should do it. (Taking for granted that you didn't changed the asset pipelines default config).

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html for more.

Comment: Unfortunately that doc doesn't address when controllers are in sub-folders and namespaces...

Comment: `//= require admin/customer_service/tickets` is your application.js. Most people just have `//= require_tree .` and it takes care of all your js.

Comment: @Webjedi The directive to include everything from a certain folder and all of its subfolders is `require_tree`. If application.js contains the directive `require_tree .`, then every JavaScript file within `assets` will be included.